# What to use instead of getRequest()->get(...) in controller

Tags: symfony

Recently I browsed symfony2 api docs and here is what i've found in documentation for Request's [get](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get) method:

> Avoid using this method in controllers:
>
> - slow
> - prefer to get from a "named" source

So what is the `"named" source` that I should use instead of `get` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"named" source would be appropriate parameter bag:

- `$request->query` for GET parameters
- `$request->attributes` for request attributes (parsed from PATH_INFO)
- `$request->request` for POST parameters

`get` method simply goes through all of them until it finds a parameter by name. Therefore its slow. See [the implementation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/53fad04f3e7cdcd37a0a4b0c225c3e8c25078b78/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L527).