# Retrieving GET and POST data inside Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, http-post, http-get

I've been searching the web for how to get POST data inside the controller, so far I have found two solutions: `Input::get()` and `$_POST`.

The comment for `Input::get()` reads:

```
/**
 * Gets a "parameter" value.
 *
 * This method is mainly useful for libraries that want to provide some flexibility.
 *
 * Order of precedence: GET, PATH, POST
 *
 * Avoid using this method in controllers:
 *
 *  * slow
 *  * prefer to get from a "named" source
 *
 * It is better to explicitly get request parameters from the appropriate
 * public property instead (query, attributes, request).
 *
 * @param string  $key     the key
 * @param mixed   $default the default value
 * @param Boolean $deep    is parameter deep in multidimensional array
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
```

What is this "named" source they refer to? What is it I should use instead of `Input::get()` ?

Comment: They probably refer to $_GET or $_POST, i.e. if you know where your parameter comes from there is not need to test first GET and then POST parameters.

Comment: Jan, where did you get the comments from?

Comment: The comment comes from the Symfony component used by Laravel 4: Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php

Comment: See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240165/what-to-use-instead-of-getrequest-get-in-controller" for your answer.

Comment: @RobGordijn How do we get the `$request` object?

Comment: with `App::request()`

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/requests) shows you can retrieve an input value for any HTTP verb by using  `Input::get()`.

```
$name = Input::get('name');
```

Comment: To be a little more explicit - the documentation says: "You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb used for the request, as input is accessed in the same way for all verbs." and that's the Input::get() method. If you need to differentiate between verbs, you can use different routes for different verbs, or use Request::isMethod('post') for example to determine if you're handling a HTTP POST request.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of this behaviour and prefer getting only input from the request body on POST requests and, similarly, only input from the query string on GET requests. I do really like using `Input::get` however so I've extended the Laravel Request class and overrode the `input` method so that it doesn't add the query string parameters to every search set. It was a very simple change. Extending the Request class is well documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/extending#request-extension

Comment: To expand on @Colin's answer, extend the Laravel Request class with your own, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30840179/517371 Then, in your class, copy the `input()` method from `Illuminate\Http\Request` and remove ` + $this->query->all()`. Bingo! Now in a POST request, `Request::query()` returns the query (URL) parameters, while `Request::input()` returns the form / multipart / JSON / whatever parameters.

Comment: Question: "What is it I should use instead of Input::get()" Answer: "Input::get()" 

Answer (score 2):

TO get all the inputs use `Input::all()` method.
To check if specific column exists use `Input::has('column_name')` eg.`Input::has('name')`.
To retrieve column value use `Input::get('column_name')` eg. `Input::get('name')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a parameter from url using :-

```
request()->urlParam;
```

if you want to get GET parameter using :-

```
$request->get('current-password');
```

if you want to get POST parameter using :-

```
$request->post('current-password');
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern Laravel installs, if your controller method is passed an instance of `Request` then [you can use that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input). For example, all these are identical:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Model $model) {
    $some_var = $_POST["some_var"];
    $some_var = $request->input("some_var");
    $some_var = $request->post("some_var");
    $some_var = $request->some_var;
}
```

If your method is not passed an instance of the current `Request` you can use [the `request()` helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request) to access one.