# Use $_GET variables from inside controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5. How do I use the $_GET variables inside my controller? This is my HTML;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/contracts/refine">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postcodes:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select name="postcode_dataset_id">
                  <option value="1">February 2015</option>
                  <option value="2">May 2015</option>
                  <option value="3">August 2015</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 15px;">Load</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form it's going to my route.php;

```
Route::get('/contracts/refine', ['as' => 'postcodes-dataset-refine', 'uses' => 'ContractsController@refine']);
```

Now I want the result of the form in my Controller method so I can actually use it! So far I have this in my refine method in my controller;

```
public function refine()
{
    print $_GET['postcodes_dataset_id'];
}
```

But I keep getting this error and I don't know what it means

```
ErrorException in ContractsController.php line 44:
Undefined index: postcodes_dataset_id
```

I tried to define it by going;

```
public function refine()
{
  $postcodes_dataset_id = "";
  print $_GET['postcodes_dataset_id'];
}
```

But that does nothing!

UPDATE - This is the top of my controller.. just to show you what namespaces I already have registered;

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Contract;
use App\Models\PostcodeLookup;
use App\Models\Location;
use App\Models\Lookup;
//use Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class ContractsController extends Controller {
```

Comment: typo? `postcode_dataset_id` is you select name, you retrieve it with `$_GET['postcodes_dataset_id']` (see the extra 's' in 'postcodes')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely retrieve input using the `Request` class.

Either with the facade: (make sure to add `use Request;` at the top of your class)

```
echo Request::input('postcode_dataset_id');
```

Or by injecting the request:

```
public function refine(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    echo $request->input('postcode_dataset_id');
}
```

---

Also you seem to have a typo in there.

```
postcode_dataset_id !== postcodes_dataset_id
//                              ^
```

Comment: When I include `use Request` I get the error `Cannot use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request because the name is already in use` - which I don't understand

Comment: If you want to use the facade, remove `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` if you have added that import statement because you need it give `Request` an alias name or use dependency injection right away

Comment: Ok.. It works :) What is the difference between `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and `use Request;` though? I am new to namespaces and Laravel 5 is very confusing to me at the moment.

Comment: There are two `Request` classes. One is `Illuminate\Http\Request` and the other `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`. The first one is the actual request class, the second is a [facade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades) that provides an easy access to the current request. Furthermore `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` has a global alias `Request`. This is what you're using when you write `use Request;`.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel map the request to an object to filter that input you shouldn't use `$_GET`directly in your controller.

`$name = Request::input('name');`

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: `Input::get()` is Laravel 4 not 5

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve an input value for any HTTP verb by using  `Input::get()`.

for laravel 4  [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/requests)

check the answer of [bogartalamid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21448874/552116)

```
$name = Input::get('postcodes_dataset_id');
```

for laravel 5  [document](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests)

```
$name = Request::input('postcodes_dataset_id');
```

Comment: I get the error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found` - See my update which show the namespaces I have included. What am I missing?

Comment: `Input::get()` is Laravel 4 not 5