# How receive data via post in my laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I dont know receive data by post in my laravel application.

I already build the function to receive by GET, but, i think via post would be better.

How can I do?
Is the same as normal PHP?

Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761555/retrieving-get-and-post-data-inside-controller-in-laravel-4

Comment: you first read laravel documentation it's help full for getting framework basic functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to GET

In your Router add a route:

```
Route::post('home/doStuff/{withSomeParam}', 'YourController@doStuff');
```

Then in YourController controller:

```
public function doStuff($someParamId, Request $request){
    ... do something awesome with someParamId
    return redirect('home');

}
```

And you are done =]

Comment: Thx Bro. this is way more sample that I tougth

Comment: @EricTeixeira if this works for you, don't forget to accept my answer please. =]